# LibXML2 Sax Parsing and ampersand

Tags: escaping, libxml2

I've encountered (what I think is) a strange behavior when using the sax parser, and I wanted to know if it's normal.

I'm sending this XML through the SAX parser:

```
<site url="http://example.com/?a=b&amp;b=c"; />
```

The "&" gets converted to " &" when the `startElement` callback
is called.  Is it supposed to do that?  If so, I would like to
understand why.

I've pasted an example demonstrating the issue here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

static void start_element(void * ctx, const xmlChar *name, const xmlChar **atts)
{
  int i = 0;
  while(atts[i] != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", atts[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  xmlSAXHandlerPtr handler = calloc(1, sizeof(xmlSAXHandler));
  handler->startElement = start_element;

  char * xml = "<site url=\"http://example.com/?a=b&amp;b=c\" />";

  xmlSAXUserParseMemory( handler,
                          NULL,
                          xml,
                          strlen(xml)
  );
}
```

PS: This message is actually extracted from the [LibXML2 list](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2009-June/msg00003.html)... and I am not the initial author of this mail, but I noticed the problem using [Nokogiri](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/tree/master) and [Aaron](http://tenderlovemaking.com/) (the maintainer of Nokogiri) actually posted this message himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [message](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2003-November/msg00301.html) describes the same problem (which I had as well) and [the response](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2003-November/msg00324.html) says to

> ask the parser to replace entities values

What that means is when you are setting up your context, set the option like this:

```
xmlParserCtxtPtr context = xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(&yourSAXHandlerStruct, self, NULL, 0, NULL);
xmlCtxtUseOptions(context, XML_PARSE_NOENT);
```